# How can I follow through?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, armature, bezier-curves, eevee-render-engine

How can I follow the path? or the model should be through away. I tried follow track constraint and follow curve modifier also. None of them working. Curve modifier is not working because it is rigged. or any other process to do that animation that the objecct should be thrown away from animated object. Could anyone help me?

the link is https://youtu.be/Fqm9AHVpg5Y

Comment: you need to hold then release the object, then make it follow the path

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80389)